# Livewire Dom update break jquery plugin like Select2 .. etc

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, break, laravel-livewire

I'm facing an issue when livewire DOM update jquery plugin not work , jquery plugins breaks and not working . Kindly proper guid thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When select2, I solved the issue by doing the next

```
//in component
public $selectedElem;

public function hydrate()
{
   $this->emit('select2Hydrate');
}

public function updatedSelectedElem($value)
{
   dd($value);
}

//in blade
<select class="form-control select2_livewire" wire:model="selectedElem">
   //.....
</select>

<script>
 
  $(document).ready(function() {

      window.loadSelect2 = () => {
         $('.select2_livewire').select2().on('change',function () {
             @this.set('selectedElem',$(this).val());
         });
      }
      loadSelect2();
      window.livewire.on('select2Hydrate',()=>{
         loadSelect2();
      });  
  }   

</script>
```